# Screen lighting on Kotlin when Push notification arrives

Tags: android, notifications, push, alert, screen

When the application is closed, and the phone screen is off, the phone receives push notifications. At this time, Android phones can receive push notifications, but they don’t turn the screen on.

Please tell me how to turn the screen on of a turned off phone screen when push notifications from the application come in.

Answer (score 0):

You can not control that as far as I know in modern Android.
It's up to the individual user to set up the system setting to allow push notifications to turn on the screen.

As an example in Android 11 the setting is under
`Lock Screen -> Wake Lock screen for notifications`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).